# how to implement bitwise color codin in blackberry

Tags: blackberry-storm

i am new to blackberry.Currently i am working upon bitmap color coding

The code which i am implement for changing colors of image are as follows:
Bitmap greyScale = new Bitmap(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight());

```
    int[] argb = new int[original.getWidth() * original.getHeight()];

    original.getARGB(argb, 0, original.getWidth(), 0, 0, original.getWidth(), original.getHeight());
    for (int i = argb.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
```

{
            int alpha = argb[i] >> 24;
            int red = argb[i] >> 16 & 0xFF;
            int green = argb[i] >> 8 & 0xFF;
            int blue = 255-argb[i] & 0xFF;

```
         int  grey = (int) (0.3 * red + 0.59 * green + 0.11 * blue);

        int red2 = red * contrast/10+brightness;
        if (red2>0xFF) red2 = 0xFF;
        if (red2<0) red2 = 0;
        int green2 = green * contrast/10+brightness;
        if (green2>0xFF) green2 = 0xFF;
        if (green2<0) green2 = 0;
        int blue2 = blue * contrast/10+brightness;
        if (blue2>0xFF) blue2 = 0xFF;
        if (blue2<0) blue2 = 0;

        int composite = (alpha << 24) | (red2 << 16) | (green2 << 8) | blue2|red|green;
        argb[i] = composite;
    }

    greyScale.setARGB(argb, 0, original.getWidth(), 0, 0, original.getWidth(), original.getHeight());

    return greyScale;
}
```

I am capable of implementing this method and capable of obtaining various colors also.
But can anyone help me that how Argb is working on the entire code for colors.

regards
Pinkesh Gupta

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I am using your code with some modifications. To answer your question,

Each byte in argb is a 32-bit value representing one pixel in 0xAARRGGBB format:

- 8 bits alpha (transparency): 0 for transparent and 255 for opaque
- 8 bits red
- 8 bits green
- 8 bits blue

So 0xFFFFFFFF would be opaque white.

The code to extract the values works as follows:
To get the apha value, shift everything right by 24 places leaving only the first 8 bits

```
int alpha = argb[i] >> 24
```

To get red, shift right by 16, leaving the top 16 bits. Then blank out the top 8 bits using the AND operator. This leaves the second 8 bits

```
int red = argb[i] >> 16 & 0xFF
```

For green, shift by 8 bits and blank out first 16 bits, leaving the third 8 bits

```
int green = argb[i] >> 8 & 0xFF
```

And finally for blue, just blank out the top 24 bits

```
int blue = argb[i] & 0xFF;
```

At this point you can make changes to the alpha,red,green and blue values. I am using

```
int grey = ( red + green + blue ) / 3;
red = grey;
green = grey;
red = grey;
```

To get a grayscale version of the bitmap.

Finally, to make up a new value, shift every part to the correct place and superimpose them (which happens to be the same as adding them in this case)

```
int newval = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
```

Then set `argb[i] = newval` to replace the pixel.